# cloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(); no container created and no exception thrown

Tags: c#, azure, containers

AbsoluteUri = "https://auspexous.blob.core.windows.net/101351"
-- creates container as expected

AbsoluteUri = "https://auspexous.blob.core.windows.net/101351R"
-- no container created and no exception in try catch

Code below:

```
if (azacctid != null)
                        {
                            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select AccountName, AccountKey, ConnectionString1, URL  from AzureStorageAccount where accountid = " + azacctid, sqlConnection))
                            {
                                //sqlConnection.Open();
                                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                                while (rdr.Read())
                                {
                                    accountname = rdr["AccountName"].ToString();
                                    containername = incidentid.ToString();
                                    accountkey = rdr["AccountKey"].ToString();
                                    ConnectionString = rdr["ConnectionString1"].ToString();

                                    CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionString);
                                    CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                               
                                    CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containername);
                                    cloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

                                    CloudBlobContainer rcloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containername+"R");
                                    rcloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

                                }
                                rdr.Close();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Select a storage account.");

                        }
```

Comment: `AbsoluteUri = "https://auspexous.blob.core.windows.net/101351R"` - This should have failed with `400 (Bad Request)` error because the name of the container is invalid (contains an uppercase letter).